# Fixing Issue in a simple text field value changer using basic HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Need help making a simple text editor :
Text is displayed on screen
Click on Text to change it
Click change button to see the changes

but program goes in an infinite oop

```
var creators = {
hTag :function(textToInput){
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  var div  = document.getElementById('main');
  div.innerHTML = '';
  h1.id = 'userText';
  h1.textContent = textToInput;
  div.appendChild(h1);
  console.log(div);
  listeners.hTagListener();
  //document.querySelector('h1');
  //hTag.addEventListener('click',this.);
},
changeField :function(){
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var div = document.getElementById('main');
  div.innerHTML='';
  button.id = 'changeButton';
  button.textContent = 'Change';
  input.id = 'input';
  input.type = 'text';
  div.appendChild(button);
  div.appendChild(input);
  listeners.changeButtonListener();

}
};

var listeners = {
hTagListener : function(){
  var h1Print = document.querySelector('h1');
  h1Print.addEventListener('click',creators.changeField());
  console.log('added event listener');
},
changeButtonListener : function(){
var but = document.getElementById('changeButton');
  var inputText = document.getElementById('input');
  console.log(inputText.value);
but.addEventListener('click',creators.hTag(inputText.value));}
};

creators.hTag('initialValue');
```

and my Main HTML is

```html
 <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
 <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
```

Expected :
In the last line of javascript, a header tag is appended to div 
which has textContent 'initialValue'.
After Clicking on it :
A text Field and change button should appear,
on clicking change, new Value must be displayed as Header!

Actual : 
Program goes in an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding event listener you are calling actual function instead of that you should just bind the event the modified code is below

```
 var listeners = {
    hTagListener : function(){
      var h1Print = document.querySelector('h1');
      h1Print.addEventListener('click',creators.changeField);
      console.log('added event listener');
    },
    changeButtonListener : function(){
    var but = document.getElementById('changeButton');
      var inputText = document.getElementById('input');
    but.addEventListener('click',function(){creators.hTag(inputText.value)},false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently addEventListener click methods are directly executing onload of the screen. Due to this execution is going for the infinite loop. To avoid this bind the method as below

```
var listeners = {
hTagListener : function(){
  var h1Print = document.querySelector('h1');
  h1Print.addEventListener('click',creators.changeField.bind(this), false);
  console.log('added event listener');
},
changeButtonListener : function(){
  var but = document.getElementById('changeButton');
  var inputText = document.getElementById('input');
  console.log(inputText.value);
but.addEventListener('click',creators.hTag.bind(this, inputText.value));
}
};
```